# Handling circular dependencies in Linq to SQL when inserting rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to work with an existing, shared database (I cannot modify the database design) with Linq-to-SQL and .NET 4.5 in C#. The database is on SQL Server 2008.

In order to clarify what my problem is, I created a minimal working example:

Consider the following (meaningless) example, where two tables represent people and companies. Every person works for exactly one company (no jobless here), and each company is led by exactly one person:

[image]

I want to use Linq-to-SQL to create a new company and a new person, which leads it.

I would have coded something like this:

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) {
    var company = new daCompany() { name = "company1" };
    var person = new daPerson() { name = "person1" };
    company.daPerson = person;
    person.daCompany = company;
    ctx.daCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(company);
    ctx.daPersons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

but `SubmitChanges()` throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: A cycle was detected in the set of changes

I could try to insert the company first, but this will lead to another exception, which complains about the violated foreign key constraint (missing leader).

Is there any way to bypass this problem *without* touching the database design or transferring the creation of the rows to a stored procedure?

Comment: One side of the relationship has to support 0-1 relationship for this to work. Either the person can be disassociated from a company or a company can be leader-less... at least for a bit. Without that, even a stored procedure won't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't even solve this problem with raw SQL. You have a mutual foreign key dependency. You have created two tables into which you can never insert any rows.

You could create one dummy row in each table while the foreign key is disabled. Then you can first insert both rows pointing to dummy rows. Then, you update them to set in the real values now that the mutual IDs are known.

I recommend making one of the foreign key columns nullable so that you can insert the two rows one after the other. But you said you don't want to modify the schema.

Comment: unfortunately the database scheme is not created by me, I just have to work with it. Currently all creations are handled by stored procedures (which can disable the verification of FK constraints), but this seems too cumbersome to me

Comment: Can you execute DDL? You can disable the FKs yourself. There is no way in SQL Server to insert into two tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

usually you need to Insert only one entity. But I am afraid that you'd need 1..0-1 relation.

Have you tried this code?

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext()) 
{
var company = new daCompany() { name = "company1" };
var person = new daPerson() { name = "person1" };
company.daPerson = person;
person.daCompany = company;
ctx.daCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(company);
//ctx.daPersons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried this, unfortunately it won't work either (same Exception)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the normal forms in the database design the above scenario should be broken down and 3 tables will have to be created. 2 tables (Person and Company) having their own primary keys which do not depend on each other and a third table (PersonCompanyRelation) that will have the dependent foreign keys on both Person and Company, that will define the relationship.

[EDIT]: Link to support the above argument, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386950(v=vs.90).aspx